# Chaining function/stored procedure calls

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I would like to compose stored procedures or functions to evaluate ad-hoc queries or filters.  Is it possible to compose functions or stored procedures with table valued parameters?

Suppose we have:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTbl(
    Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(max),
    Quantity INT)
```

With a corresponding user defined table type:

```
CREATE TYPE TResult AS TABLE(
    Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    Name NVARCHAR(max),
    Quantity INT)
```

A basic select all function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Generator()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN SELECT Id, Name, Quantity
FROM TestTbl
```

Some filters that accept a `TResult` parameter and with which I would like to compose the user's query, e.g.:

```
CREATE FUNCTION F1(
    @in TResult READONLY)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN SELECT Id, Name, Quantity
       FROM @In
       WHERE Name LIKE '%h%'
```

`SELECT * FROM Generator()` produces the expected results.
How can I do something like?

```
SELECT *
FROM F1(Generator())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create table with type of TResult. And after that pass this table as parameter.

```
SELECT *
FROM F1(@tresulttable)
```